# Command line argument as default to a function defined in another module

Tags: python, environment-variables

Lets say I have two modules within a package, `one.py` and `two.py`, plus a `config.py`.  I want to execute `one.py` on the command line and pass an argument that is available as the default to a function in `two.py`... By way of example:

### one.py:

```
import sys, getopt
import config

def main(argv):
    opts, _ = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hs', ['--strict='])
    for opt, _ in opts:
        if opt in ('-s', '--strict'):
            config.strict = True

    import two
    two.foo()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

### two.py

```
from config import strict
def foo(s=strict):
    if s:
        print "We're strict"
    else:
        print "We're relaxed around these parts"
```

### config.py

```
strict = False
```

Now, this works but seems clunky and poor form what with the import in the middle of my `main` function... I assume there is a way to do this with decorators? Or one of the lazy evaluation modules, but I'm at a loss!  What is the most pythonic way to use a command line argument as a default to a function defined in another module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default by overwriting the function's `func_defaults` (`__defaults__` in python3.x) attribute:

```
>>> def foo(a=True):
...     print a
... 
>>> foo()
True
>>> foo.func_defaults
(True,)
>>> foo.func_defaults = (False,)
>>> foo()
False
>>>
```

I don't know that I would say that this is "pythonic".  As far as I'm concerned, the most pythonic solution would be to just pass the argument:

```
import two
def main(argv):
    opts, _ = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hs', ['--strict='])
    for opt, _ in opts:
        if opt in ('-s', '--strict'):
            config.strict = True

    two.foo(s=config.strict)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree that passing the arg is the best choice... but the greater goal is to be able to toggle "strictness" in a `voluptuous` schema validator so I can toggle acceptance of `None` type as well as the defined type.